# Trying to readjust the title of the multilingual website when searching through Google

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, language

As of this moment, I am making adjustments to SEO through Google Search Console for a company website.

The site is built using Nuxt2 with i18n for multilingual support.

I have a problem with the name of the site, specifically the small piece of text right above the large blue text. Originally, the site is supposed to be listed under a Japanese title. However, it is listed in English.
Is it possible to somehow edit the title to be in Japanese? The only page that is listed inside the rich snippet is  the Japanese main page with the subdomain "/ja".

Has anyone had this kind of problem before? What is the possible solution for this problem? I am aware that Google automatically selects the right title for the website. Is there a way to influence Google to set the title of the website?

Please let me know in the comments. Thank you!

Comment: Its difficult to comment without data :-)

Comment: Comment from @TomNewton.  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43009/is-it-bad-to-use-japanese-characters-in-search-friendly-urls